# Retrieve information from partial google protobuf message

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers, tcp

I am working on a project which involves communication between two apps in c++ and python respectively. They will talk via TCP using google protobuf. For now, the design of my message is like:

```
raw_msg
{
    required int32 len = 1;
    required int32 name_len = 2;
    required string type_name = 3;
    required bytes data = 4;
}
[other msgs....]
```

So there are many message types and they will all be packed into a `raw_msg` before sent and on the receiver side, it will first get the `len` of the whole raw message and block before there is not enough data. Once the data is good to retrieve the complete message, the decoding will begin.

My question is that as the length of `raw_msg` is also not fixed, how can I get the `len` field? For example, if now in my buffer, there is only `len` and `name_len`, can I use

```
raw_msg.ParseFromString(buffer)
```

and `raw_msg.len()` to get the `len` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to encode the length separately, not as part of the message itself. There is generally no guarantee that just because `len` has field number 1, that it will be encoded before the other fields -- it is in fact legal for it to appear at the end of the message, or anywhere in between.

What you probably want to do is follow the semi-standard "delimited" format, in which you encode the length of the message as a "varint" before encoding the message itself. A "varint" is a variable-length base-128 integer, described in the protobuf docs. I'm not sure if the Python API has publicly-accessible helper methods for encoding this, unfortunately (C++ and Java do).

On another note, consider using a `oneof` declaration to distinguish between different body message types, rather than using a type name and a string. `oneof` is more type-safe, easier to understand, more efficiently encoded on the wire, and avoids the need to double-parse/encode.